# Unable to display the result in View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Defined model like below (No property, but just one method):

```
namespace PartyInvitesInProASPNETMVC5.Models
{
    public class MyAsyncMethods
    {
        public static Task<long?> GetPageLength()
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            var httpTask = client.GetAsync("http://www.google.com");
            return httpTask.ContinueWith((Task<HttpResponseMessage> antecedent) => {
                return antecedent.Result.Content.Headers.ContentLength;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Written Controller Action Method like below:

```
public ActionResult GooglePageLength()
{
    var content = MyAsyncMethods.GetPageLength();
    return View(content);
}
```

I am not understanding how to generate view for the above action method. Modified code like below from the default generated view. But, still getting error.

```
@model PartyInvitesInProASPNETMVC5.Models.MyAsyncMethods.GetPageLength()
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Google Page Length</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>@Convert.ToInt32(@Model)@*How to write code here?*@
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is the error I am getting:

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2[System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage,System.Nullable`1[System.Int64]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]'.

Comment: You passing a model which is typeof `long?` so therefore the it must be `@model long?`. The code you have shown cannot generate that error - but it will generate a _Compilation Error_ because the `@model` declaration cannot be a method. You need to show your real code.

Comment: @Stephen: Sorry for late response. Believe me, it is real code.

Comment: No its not because a different exception is thrown if you really had a method in the model declaration.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Modified the action method like below.

```
public ActionResult WellsFargoPageLength()
{
ViewBag.PageLength = MyAsyncMethods.GetPageLength().Result;
return View();
}
```

Deleted the View and created once again keeping the above modified action method in mind.

Answer (score 1):

You should wait for the result in the controller with await:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GooglePageLength()
{
    long? content = await MyAsyncMethods.GetPageLength();
    return View(content);
}
```

Then make your view model type `long?`:

```
@model long?
```

You are currently passing the task that completes asynchronously to the view. And you are also setting the model type as the function that returns the task (did not know you could even do that).

Normally you should wait for the result of the task asynchronously with await, and then return the result as the model for the view.

Comment: Whatever the code I have written is just the other way to "without using await". Anyway, your suggestion did not solve my problem. Thank you for your effort.

Comment: _did not know you could even do that_ - your cant :) - OP has not shown us the correct code.